# Convert comma separated string into several lists and ignore first 5 characters of string's first element Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, string-parsing

I'm pretty new in Java and now i have following problem which I'm trying to solve.

I have a string like this:

```
item1item2,item3,item4item5,item6,item7
```

and what i need to get is this 2 lists:

```
{item2,item3,item4}
{item5,item6,item7}
```

Please note that item1 is being omitted in this list and also there's no comma between item4 and item5

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are going to want to look at `String.split()`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: Once you split things between the commas, how do you know which parts of which pieces to drop & which to split?

Comment: That's what i did in the first place but my case is kind of specific, as it's not just simple String.split() function.

Comment: Why don't you do two different things? Split, then take care of your first element?

Comment: Scott, sorry but i didn't understand your question.. can you please rephrase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be easiest to first split this into two strings using the `subString()` method, the first containing items 2, 3, 4 and the second 5, 6, 7. Then after that you can use `String.split()` to get what you want.

Comment: I just tried using substring to remove first several characters that i don't need and it worked on the first part when i need to split between item1 and item2 to start with item2, i guess the same thing i can do with the rest of the string. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will work in this specific case.

```
String string = "item1item2,item3,item4item5,item6,item7";
string = string.substring(5, string.length);
String[] list1 = string.substring(0, string.length/2).split(',');
String[] list2 = string.substring(string.length/2, string.length).split(',');
```